# How to set a ListView's ItemsSource to a DependencyProperty inside a custom UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom user control like this:

```
<ListView Name="listView" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Containers}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Info" Width="150">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

```
public partial class ContainerList : UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable<Container> Containers
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable <Container>)GetValue(ContainersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContainersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Containers", typeof(IEnumerable<Container>), typeof(ContainerList), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ContainerList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        listView.ItemsSource = Containers;
    }

    private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var selectedContainer = (Container)listView.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedContainer.Children.Any())
            {
                childContainerList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                childContainerList.ItemsSource = selectedContainer.Children;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm creating it inside MainWindow like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:ContainerList Containers="{Binding Containers}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Container> Containers
    {
        get => _containers;
        set
        {
            _containers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

This control would be recursive in the end.
Now the problem is, the ListView doesn't populate at all. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext to itself, because that breaks the standard data binding behaviour. It is also pointless to set the ListView's ItemsSource in the UserControl constructor, because there is already a Binding in XAML.

```
public ContainerList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The Binding should however use the UserControl instance as its source object, e.g. like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Containers,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

---

As a note, `new PropertyMetadata(null)` will set the PropertyChangedCallback of the dependency property to `null`, not the default value.

Unless you actually want to set any specific values, do not pass property metadata at all:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Containers),
        typeof(IEnumerable<Container>),
        typeof(ContainerList));
```